# How to Prefill Data Inside The Quill Js Editor In Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need a little help here.

I have some data gotten from an api in my angular application.

I want to prefill the value of the data I am getting inside the Quill Editor input box.
The Quill Editor doesn't work with the html
`value`
attribute, so this doesn't work: `[value]="paymentMessage ? paymentMessage.message_before_payment : ''"`

So far, I can only display the data as a placeholder instead of an actual value.
Here is my code below:

```
 <quill-editor
            [styles]="editorStyle"
            name="form"
            [placeholder]="paymentMessage ? paymentMessage.message_before_payment : ''"
            [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
 >
 </quill-editor>
```

Here is the result I get:
[image]

If I use the `[innerHtml]` attribute. The data will display outside the input field instead of it displaying inside the input field.

I'll really appreciate any help I can get.

Here is a link to their npm site. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill

Answer (score 3):

Hi i think is better to set custom value component.ts instead of html.

Like this:

component.html

```
  <ngx-quill #editor [(ngModel)]="content" [modules]="modules"  (contentChanged)="logChange($event);"></ngx-quill>
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  content='my text'

  titleName = 'Angular';
  modules = {
    toolbar: [      
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  };
}
```

I leave you a link of stackbliz to have some running exemple of solution ;).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quill-editor-15qhyp

link of a repo with some different example: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill-example

Comment: Thanks. I checked the link to the solution you left on stackblitz, the input box is empty.

Comment: You got right there was a problem with formula module and did not update due to a console error. Now i had remove it and works.

I also found this repo with some usefull example: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill-example

Comment: I had also updated  my anwser with the solution, hope this can solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

try this here!

```js
 @ViewChild('editorText') editorText!: QuillViewComponent;
 
 private content: any;
 
 ngAfterViewInit():{
    this.content = '<p>return back-end</p>
   //fill this variable with what comes from your database
   
   this.editorText.content = this.content;
 }
```

```html
  <quill-editor #editorText></quill-editor>
```

Comment: Does not work with HTML. Only works with plain text.